# Android ORMLite : Creating Additional Database along with the Existing one

Tags: android, sqlite, ormlite

I already have a SQLite database called `songs` and I am using ORMLite to perform operations for the same.

However, I need to add another database **without using ORMLite** since I need to create new tables on runtime. Also, I am not required to make any change to the `songs` database.

I have a few questions before I attempt to do that:

1. Do I need to regenerate the ORMLite configuration file for `songs` even if I am creating a new independent database altogether?
2. Will ORMLite run erroneously if I create and maintain another database without using ORMLite?